# Return outside function error

Tags: python

This is my code and I simply want it to read the input and if it is not empty just return what was inputted.

```
print "Welcome to translator!"
print "Enter in an english word"
original=raw_input("Enter a word")

if len(original) != 0:
     return original
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only `return` from within a function So that would produce a `SyntaxError`.

A proper way to achieve what you want is by:

```
print "Welcome to translator!"
print "Enter in an english word"
original = raw_input("Enter a word")

if original: # Checks if original is not empty
     print original
```

If you want to return from a function:

```
print "Welcome to translator!"
print "Enter in an english word"
original=raw_input("Enter a word")

def not_empty(string):
     if string:
        return string

print not_empty(original)
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to coding. I'm self-studying using code academy and coding in canopy. How would I define a function here? I have seen the new edit you just made and that works.

Comment: oh ok yeah that makes sense and I see why the first is more efficient. Well at least I think it is.

Comment: I did. I use math stack exchange a lot. I just had to wait 10 mins haha.

Answer (score 1):

From the Python Official Website:

> `return` may only occur syntactically nested in a function definition,
>   not within a nested class definition.
>
> If an expression list is present, it is evaluated, else None is
>   substituted.
>
> `return` leaves the current function call with the expression list (or
>   None) as return value.
>
> When `return` passes control out of a try statement with a finally
>   clause, that finally clause is executed before really leaving the
>   function.
>
> In a generator function, the `return` statement is not allowed to
>   include an expression_list. In that context, a bare return indicates
>   that the generator is done and will cause StopIteration to be raised.